# google maps for android crashes in xamarin.forms

Tags: google-maps, xamarin.forms

I am rendering the google maps for android

The first time I load a page with google maps it works, but when I close the page and reopen it, I get the exception:

> System.NotSupportedException: Unable to activate instance of type SmartScout.Droid.CustomMapRenderer from native handle 0xcc700019 (key_handle 0x433fb7f8).

I see that the `OnElementChanged` in the `MapRenderer` is called twice and the second time it crashes with the exception above.

my code is:

```
    protected override void OnElementChanged(Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.View> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (e.OldElement != null)
        {
            return;
            //map.InfoWindowClick -= OnInfoWindowClick;
        }

        if (e.NewElement != null)
        {
            var formsMap = (CustomMap)e.NewElement;
            //customPins = formsMap.CustomPins;
            ((MapView)Control).GetMapAsync(this);
        }
    }
```

Any solutions?

Comment: What does your `OnElementChanged()` code look like? What line of the code does it crash on? Need more information than just an error message. Also is there more info in the exception after `native handle 0xcc700019 (key_handle 0x433fb7f8)`?

Comment: Can you upload a reproduction sample?

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
((MapView)Control).GetMapAsync(this);
```

and add this code

```
var androidMapView = (MapView)Control;
```

My full working code is following

```
    protected override void OnElementChanged(Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.ElementChangedEventArgs<View> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);


        var formsMap = (ExtendedMap)e.NewElement;

        var androidMapView = (MapView)Control;

        if (androidMapView != null && androidMapView.Map != null)
        {
            androidMapView.Map.InfoWindowClick += MapOnInfoWindowClick;
        }

        if (formsMap != null)
        {
            //code for run first time only
        }

  }
```